# Distributing a Python Anaconda App via RPM

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, rpm, conda

I've developed a Python app (specifically, a `Flask` RESTful API served by `gunicorn`) in an Anaconda environment.  The app was developed in Anaconda because that's what's on my own (Windows 10) machine, but I've tried to stick with Anaconda (or actually, `conda`) because of the app's heavy reliance on `pandas`, `NumPy`, and `SciPy`.  I am the sole Python programmer on a team that works mostly in Java, something that befuddles my teammates, and, for distribution (on our AWS clusters, and possibly elsewhere), my boss wants me to wrap everything up with a nice `RPM` bow.

I've spent the past week pulling my hair out over how to do this.  I've learned a lot, but I'm still pretty lost.  In bullet-point form, here are my current considerations:

- I'm not in dire need of creating an executable vs. a Python script:  I've got 4 entry-point scripts, which makes a single-file deployment problematic (I know I could make a single script that calls each of the others, but I've got better things to do, and anyway some of the scripts would be run by different users than the others), and I don't see much point, other than aesthetic, of transforming the entry points to executables. In any case, I'm not sure I know how to get `PyInstaller` or the like working with both `conda` and `RPM`.
- Using `setuptools` with the `bdist_rpm` argument seems like the straightforward solution, but I'm leery of anything that uses `pip` rather than `conda` for installs, due to `pip`'s problems with non-Python dependencies.  I realize that `pip` on Linux probably won't fall down as badly as `pip` on Windows, but I still don't trust `pip` (should I in this case?).  Perhaps if I'm distributing copies of the whole environment, packages included, the dependency-handling is easier, but I haven't seen anything in my research to tell me whether or not that's true.
- It looks like I could hack something together with `RPM` or `Make`, but I'm not positive I know how do that.

I would be happy to get any advice on the best way to proceed.

Comment: pip works just fine on windows, pretty much same as on Linux. Why are you actually worried about it? It's a fairly mature program. Also, conda is designed specifically to be interoperable with pip. It won't mess up your environment.

Comment: I use a mix of conda and pip on both Linux and Windows consistently. I usually use conda for the big stuff like numpy and scipy that I always need in my repos, and do the rest through pip.

Comment: If you spec out your dependencies properly, I don't expect you'll have any issues.

Comment: Did you try [pyp2rpm](https://github.com/fedora-python/pyp2rpm)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that one--thanks.  It doesn't look like there's any way to integrate it with conda, though, and I'm not even sure what advantage it gives me over setuptools.